# What is CGI and what are CGI Scripts?

Tags: apache, cgi

Ive seen a folder called cgi-bin quite long while using apache.

How do scripts help me?

how can i use them?

I've used php and ajax only for web development!

Comment: [This](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/cgi/) is a great tutorial on CGI.

Comment: When you Googled CGI, what did you learn?  Anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

G'day,

A web server, e.g. Apache, just sends back static content is response to a client request for content. For example a request for http://www.myserver.com/index.html typically causes the server to open the file and return the content of the file wrapped with the relevant http components.

Basically CGI is a technique for generating such web pages dynamically via other applications which are run by the web server on an as-needed basis.

The directory cgi-bin is typically used to house the scripts being run.

Though it's heavily focused on Perl The book "[CGI Programming with Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565924193)" has an excellent intro about CGI.

**Edit:** As asked in the comments below, "if PHP can take care of dynamic content, then what's the need for CGI". There's a few points here.

1. out of the box, PHP can be pretty slow. CGI, especially in its mod_perl guise, or when using app's built in compiled languages,
2. PHP doesn't have very strong error handling, but this can be worked around,
3. I don't think that there's real support for ASP, Windows app's or DB's, and
4. PHP security is a bit of a worry, e.g. having register_globals enabled, and PHP's flaws are extremely well known.

The design of the PHP language itself also contains many inconsistencies, e.g.

- a fairly useless object model,
- scoping is fairly bad,
- inconsistent naming, and
- poor organisation of the standard library.

I believe that PHP5 goes a long way to improving these points.

While security is always a concern, with CGI implementations you are able to minimise the security problem in well publicised ways.

HTH

cheers,

Comment: thanks for the reply rob :)
php can take care of dynamic content rite?
then wats the need for cgi???

Comment: @dineshbabu, hope I answered your question with the above edit. (-:

Comment: @rob: so you mean CGI is another server side programming language like PHP????? and what is the difference between CGI and Java Servlets????

Comment: @Hardik, CGI isn't a language. It's an acronym for Common Gateway Interface. There's a good intro over at Wikipedia <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface> HTH :-)

Comment: @Rob Wells thanx for answer but still i can't understand What the CGI Is??, is it a container for Perl Scripts like Servlet Container to execute Servlet Classes..........??????????

Answer (score 1):

cgi-bin stands for CGI binary. To be honest, if you're acquainted with PHP already then you've likely little need for old-fashioned CGI scripts.